# Add and decrease time with UIButton to Timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nstimer

Hello everyone i have a question how i can add and decrease time with UIButton to timer for example if i will have button with minus and plus and time at timer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  UIButton *buttonPlus = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  UIButton *buttonMinus = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

 [buttonPlus addTarget:self action:@selector(addTime) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [buttonMinus addTarget:self action:@selector(removeTime) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 [self.view addSubview:buttonMinus];
 [self.view addSubview:buttonPlus];

}

-(void) addTime {
    [yourTimer setFireDate:[[yourTimer fireDate] dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsToAdd]];
}

-(void) removeTime {
    [yourTimer setFireDate:[[yourTimer fireDate] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-secondsToAdd]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could add time to a NSTimer using this:

```
[yourTimer setFireDate:[[yourTimer fireDate] dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsToAdd]];
```

You could decrease time to a NSTimer using:

```
[yourTimer setFireDate:[[yourTimer fireDate] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-secondsToDecrease]];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's obvious but this methods must be call from UIAction binded with plus and minus UIButtons ;-)